# The usage of jQuery 'end()' function

Tags: jquery

i go to the site http://api.jquery.com/end/ just to understand how end() use and how it works. unfortunately i just do not understand what it does. so i need to know in what kind of situation end() should be used.

### here is small example

```
<ul class="first">
  <li class="foo">list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li class="bar">list item 3</li>
</ul>
<ul class="second">
  <li class="foo">list item 1</li>
  <li>list item 2</li>
  <li class="bar">list item 3</li>
</ul>

 $('ul.first')
         .find('.foo')
         .css('background-color', 'red')
         .end()
         .find('.bar')
         .css('background-color', 'green');
```

i just do not understand what kind of role `end()` function play here.

it would be great if someone help me to understand the usage of `end()` function with small & easy sample code. please help. thanks

Comment: Well you could have looked into this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745814/what-does-the-end-function-do-in-jquery

Comment: Indeed. There's clearly very little research been performed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is explained pretty well in [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/end/):

> End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

It's clearer if I render the code like so:

```
$('ul.first')
    .find('.foo')
       .css('background-color', 'red')
    .end()
    .find('.bar')
       .css('background-color', 'green');
```

It means that what you're setting `background-color` to `green` on is `ul.first .bar`, not `ul.first .foo .bar`. It *undoes* the `.find('foo')` filter in that call chain.

An equivalent would be:

```
$('ul.first').find('.foo').css('background-color', 'red');
$('ul.first').find('.bar').css('background-color', 'green');
```

Answer (score 2):

The initial selector returns all `ul` elements with the class `first`. The `.find('.foo')` returns all children of those elements with the class `foo`, then sets a background-color of red to them. The use of `.end()` returns the previous set of elements prior to the `.find()` - so, again, all `ul` elements with the class `first` - then looks for children with the class `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

> Description: End the most recent filtering operation in the current
>   chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state.

Ill explain `$('ul.first').find('.foo').css('background-color', 'red')
 .end().find('.bar').css('background-color', 'green');`. You select all the `ul.first` elements, and select all the `.foo` elements from there (and change the BG color). Next, you end the sequence, so you 'undo' your search for `.foo` elements.
Now you search for all the `.bar` elements, and change their BG color.

The function of `end()` is to stop the sequence of searches, and go up one level of searching. In the example, if there was no `end()`, there would be no `.bar` elements, because there is no `ul.first .foo .bar` element in the HTML.