# Change property of cloned element before appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, clone

I'm cloning a "template" DIV with jQuery and appending a **modified** version to another DIV.

The problem is that the changes I make to the clone, do not show up when I append it to the destination.

```
var $clone = $('div[data-id="5"]').clone();

console.log($clone.data('id')); // outputs '5'

$clone.data('id', 99);

console.log($clone.data('id')); // outputs '99'

$clone.appendTo($('#target')); // resulting cloned element has data-id of '5'! Whaa...?
```

Here's a fiddle to make it clearer: http://jsfiddle.net/ajanini/rcxd4v3b/1/ (**inspect** the element to see that the `data-id` is unchanged)

Question is: what am I doing wrong? How do I change the data-id of the clone and keep the change when I append it to the destination?

Comment: Tested in FF and Chrome, seems to work fine.

Comment: @elclanrs Are you sure? Your `data-id` was changed? Did you inspect the element?

Comment: No, but the `data` attribute is not the same as jQuery's `data`. jQuery uses its own storage.

Comment: @AlexandreReiffJanini: `.data()` is completely internal to jQuery, with the sole exception that for convenience it is prepopulated from `data-` attributes. So you are wrong to expect it to reflect in HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use this attr for setting attributes. Seems to work for me.

```
$clone.attr("data-id",99);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rcxd4v3b/2/

Comment: It doesn't just seem to work for you, it's the correct solution.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know `data` was internal to jQuery. This worked perfectly. Will accept the answer as soon as SO allows me to.

Comment: for reference, i find `end()` is also really handy when cloning and appending, as stated in this answer, it `backs out the "scope" of a chained JQuery statement to the previous level` - so you can make changes to various "levels" of the cloned element.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/1745859

Answer (score 1):

HTML `data-` (dataset) does not equal jQuery's `$().data`. Notice when you inspect a cloned element in chrome: ($0 = selected element)

```
$0.dataset.id   // 5
$($0).data('id') // 99
```

So they are separate entities, and it can get pretty confusing. You should try not to mix them.

BTW you can set the HTML markup with either `$(el).attr('data-id', id)` or with `$(el)[0].dataset.id = id`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="row session-sub-to-clone" >
    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
            <label for="parties">المشاركون</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="parties" name="participant_user_id[]">
                <option value="">المشاركون</option>
                <option value="">المشاركون</option>
                <option value="">المشاركون</option>
                <option value="">المشاركون</option>
            
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group custom-form-group">
            <label for="parties-title">عنوان المشاركة</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="partise-title" name="participant_title[]" value="" required>
            <input type="hidden" value="0" name="participant_id[]">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
        <button type="button" class="btn add-partise-btn" id="addRow"><i
                    class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="new-rows"></div>
```

The code above is a part of a **HTML FORM**  I would like to clone it and replace this **#addRow** button after it has been **cloned** and before it is appended to the form :) ...nice!

This is my code:

```
$("#addRow").click(function () {
    var html = '<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12" style="margin-right: 37%;">'
    html += '<button type="button" class="btn remove-parties-btn" id="removeRow"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>'
    html += '</div>'

    var clonedElement = $('.session-sub-to-clone').clone();

    clonedElement.find('#addRow').replaceWith(html);
    clonedElement.attr('id','inputFormRow')
    $('#new-rows').append(clonedElement);
});

// remove row
$(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
    console.log('test');
    $(this).closest('#inputFormRow').remove();
});
```

1)This HTML element "remove-btn" that i want to replace with **#addRow** button:

```
var html = '<div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12" style="margin-right: 37%;">'
html += '<button type="button" class="btn remove-partic-btn" id="removeRow"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>'
html += '</div>'
```

2)Element cloning:

```
var clonedElement = $('.session-sub-to-clone').clone();
```

3)Change and add to clonedElement:

```
clonedElement.find('#addRow').replaceWith(html);
clonedElement.attr('id','inputFormRow');
```

4)Append clonedElement to Form:

```
$('#new-rows').append(clonedElement);
```

### Best Wishes

```
                     -----------
```