# Updating id attribute using $(this) not working jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using JQuery clone() method to clone form and updating form input value's "id" attribute increment by 1.

Everything is going perfect but I'm curious about `$(this)` and `this`.

In clone() -> each() method while updating input `id` I've faced issues like when I'm updating value like:

`this.id=newId;` then its working and updating id attribute

But if I use `$(this).attr(oldId,newId)` then its not working

If I use `var old=newId` then also its not working

I've referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745814/what-does-the-end-function-do-in-jquery) and [this](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2010/08/difference-between-this-and-this-in.html) but still confused why last two methods are not working.

Full code:

```
var clonedTemplate = $(".form-section .row:first").clone();
var index = 0;
$("body").on('click', '.add', function () {
    index++;
    var formSection = clonedTemplate.clone().find(':input').each(function () {
        var oldId = $(this).attr('id');
        var newId = oldId + "_" + index;
        this.id=newId; //its working and updating id attribute
        $(this).attr(oldId,newId) // not working
        oldId=newId; // not working
    });
    formSection.end().appendTo('.form-section');
});
```

Any help/suggestion or better solution would be appreciated.

Comment: `attr` takes `attributeName` and `value`. So I'd think you would want `$(this).attr('id', newId)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to pass in the name of the attribute you are altering, not the value of it so this line

```
$(this).attr(oldId,newId)
```

needs to become

```
$(this).attr('id',newId)
```