# Is this jQuery statement a mistake: "$( "#content" ).find("h3").eq(2).html("").end()" selectects all h3's?

Tags: jquery

According to the jQuery [tutorial](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/working-with-selections/):

> jQuery also provides the .end() method to get back to the original
> selection should you change the selection in the middle of a chain:
>
> ```
> $( "#content" )
>     .find( "h3" )
>     .eq( 2 )
>         .html( "new text for the third h3!" )
>         .end() // Restores the selection to all h3s in #content
>     .eq( 0 )
>         .html( "new text for the first h3!" );
> ```

Note the comments

> **Restores the selection to all h3s in #content**

According to the [API](https://api.jquery.com/end/) and [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745814/what-does-the-end-function-do-in-jquery) end() resets back to content id selection before the h3's are selected.

Is this just wrong or has jQuery changed the behaviour since this was written. Should I open a pull request?

Comment: _"According to the API and Stackoverflow end() resets back to content id selection before the h3's are selected."_ Where did you get that? The [jQuery docs on `.end()` state](https://api.jquery.com/end/): "End the most recent filtering operation in the current chain and return the set of matched elements to its previous state."

Comment: @j08691 look at the first example. In an identical case as above: "Then end() returns the object to its state before the call to find()".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not a mistake.

`.end()` undoes the previous selection change, which was `.eq(2)`, therefore back to the same selection returned by `.find('h3')`.

It's maybe easier to understand the example with better line-breaks/indentation/comments

```
$("#content") // level 0 - original selection
.find("h3") // level 1 - change of selection
.eq(2) // level 2 - change of selection
.html( "new text for the third h3!" ) // action, but no change of selection
.end() // back to level 1 from level 2
.eq(0) // level2 - chage of selection
.html("new text for the first h3!");  // action, but no change of selection
```

In your other examples (from comments below):

```
$("body") // level 0 - original selection
.find("span") // level 1 - change of selection
.css("border", "2px red solid"); // no change of selection - css applies to span

$("body") // level 0 - original selection
.find("span") // level 1 - change of selection
.end() // back to level 0 from level 1
.css("border", "2px red solid"); // no change of selection - css applies to body
```

In the last example, `.end()` immediately nullifies the effect of `.find('span')` with no action in between on the spans.

Comment: Then the api documentation and stackoverflow question are wrong right? :)

Comment: I haven't read every word of those references but, superficially at least, they seem to be consistent and correct.

Comment: Running in my console the stackoverflow answer $("body").find("span").end().css("border", "2px red solid");  selected the body and outlined it which means the tutorial is wrong and the api is right.

Comment: Re-selecting `body` is the correct behaviour. Which statement(s) in the tutorial  lead you to believe it is wrong?

Comment: The tutorial code claims it reselects the result of the find and even tries accessing one of the h3 elements returned by find!

Comment: Because the content element is selected, not the h3's.

Comment: Compare in the console on this page $("body").find("span").css("border", "2px red solid");                     Then run:         $("body").find("span").end().css("border", "2px red solid");  and you should see why it's wrong.

Comment: You have misunderstood something. Everything behaves 100% as expected.

Comment: Now it makes sense! I made a fiddle just to make sure and you were right! https://jsfiddle.net/zudffL0g/ I hope you get some more up votes, because I was really confused without your answer.

Comment: Pheeeew! That's a relief.